# Adding delete button on the left side of the li item in JavaScript instead of the right side as default

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an unordered list in HTML with a delete button for each li then I went to CSS and set the button should be on the left side, I created my javascript to add automatic li items and I should also be able to delete items by clicking on the delete button. however, whenever I add a new item the new delete button is on the right side, how can I make it should be on the left side

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter")
var input = document.getElementById("user");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var clearButton = document.getElementsByClassName("clearButton");

function listItems() {
  return input.value.length
}

function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  var newButton = document.createElement("button");
  newButton.innerHTML = "X";
  li.appendChild(newButton);
  input.value = "";
  li.addEventListener("click", function() {
    li.classList.toggle("done");
  })

  newButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    ul.removeChild(li);

  })
}

function addItemAfterEnter() {
  if (listItems() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

function addItemAfterKeypress(event) {
  if (listItems() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addItemAfterEnter);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addItemAfterKeypress)


for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
  })
}

for (var i = 0; i < clearButton.length; i++) {
  clearButton[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentNode.remove();
  })
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15rem;
}

li button {
  color: red;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Javascript event listener</h1>
<input id="user" type="text" placeholder="enter item here">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
<p id="test"></p>
<ul>
  <li class="red blue" random="26"><button class="clearButton">X</button>lettuce</li>
  <li><button class="clearButton">X</button>apples</li>
  <li><button class="clearButton">X</button>oranges</li>
  <li><button class="clearButton">X</button>fruits</li>
  <li><button class="clearButton">X</button>candy</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When running your snippet the `X` Buttons are already on the left side. Debug CSS using your browser's developer tools (Press F12 or right-click in the browser and then "Inspect Element").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `button` to the new `li` first, and then add the `textNode`.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("enter")
var input = document.getElementById("user");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var clearButton = document.getElementsByClassName("clearButton");

function listItems() {
  return input.value.length
}

function createListElement() {
  // create the new li element
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  
  // add the button to the li
  var newButton = document.createElement("button");
  newButton.innerHTML = "X";
  li.appendChild(newButton);
  
  // then add the text to the li
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  input.value = "";

  li.addEventListener("click", function() {
    li.classList.toggle("done");
  });

  newButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    ul.removeChild(li);
  });
  
  // add the constructed li to the ul
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function addItemAfterEnter() {
  if (listItems() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

function addItemAfterKeypress(event) {
  if (listItems() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addItemAfterEnter);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addItemAfterKeypress)


for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
  })
}

for (var i = 0; i < clearButton.length; i++) {
  clearButton[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentNode.remove();
  })
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15rem;
}

li button {
  color: red;
  margin-right: .5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
}

/* bonus styles */

li:hover, li button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<h1>Javascript event listener</h1>
<input id="user" type="text" placeholder="enter item here">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
<p id="test"></p>
<ul>
  <li class="red blue" random="26"><button class="clearButton">X</button>lettuce</li>
  <li><button class="clearButton">X</button>apples</li>
  <li><button class="clearButton">X</button>oranges</li>
  <li><button class="clearButton">X</button>fruits</li>
  <li><button class="clearButton">X</button>candy</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch the order of the append child statements.

```
function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var newButton = document.createElement("button");
  newButton.innerHTML = "X";
  li.appendChild(newButton);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
  li.addEventListener("click", function() {
    li.classList.toggle("done");
  })

  newButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    ul.removeChild(li);

  })
}
```

This should work

Comment: It would help if you please copy the snippet from the question and fix it that way, so OP can see the working implementation.